# How to disable "Export" function in Adminer

Tags: php, adminer

I'm trying to disable the option to export data in Adminer 4.2.1. I found an advice that returning an empty array for [dumpFormat()](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/v4.2.1/adminer/include/adminer.inc.php#L614) like this should be working (since Adminer 3.3.4):

```
function dumpFormat() {
    return array();
}
```

But that simply causes the "Format" selection row to be blank, I can still export with whatever is the default format.
Is there a way to completely disable it?